# WIX Changing TARGETDIR conditionally

Tags: wix

I need to be able to change the TARGETDIR so that my 'logs' folder is created on the drive where the main program is installed (Drive D in this case). By searching the registry I can get the location of the main program:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" >
    <Directory Id="LOGS" Name="logs" />
</Directory>

<Property Id="KBX_INSTALLED">
  <RegistrySearch Id="KBXRegistrySearch" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\KBX" Name="InstallPath" Win64="no" Type="directory" />
</Property>
```

I've tried using CA and vbscript to change the TARGETDIR property value but the logs folder still gets created on the C drive

```
<CustomAction Id="CHANGE_TARGET" Script="vbscript">
  <![CDATA[  
    MsgBox(session.Property("TARGETDIR")) 'Returns C:\
    MsgBox(session.Property("KBX_INSTALLED")) 'Returns D:\Program Files\KBX\
    If session.property("KBX_INSTALLED") = "D:\Program Files\KBX\" Then
      session.property("TARGETDIR") = "D:\"
    End if   
    MsgBox(session.Property("TARGETDIR")) 'Returns D:\
    ]]>
</CustomAction>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CHANGE_TARGET" After="InstallValidate">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up your directory tree in Product.wxs? Within the <Product/> tag, I usually have something like `<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"><Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder"><Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="SomeCompany"><Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SomeApplication" /></Directory></Directory></Directory>`. Also,  you may try running the action with `Before="InstallValidate"` rather than `After`.

Comment: @Alexandru Thank you for your suggestions. Changing 'After' to 'Before' didn't make any difference. I am not sure why would I need to create those directories if my folder is to be created on the D drive. However if I explicitly change property of the TARGETDIR like this <Property Id="TARGETDIR" Value="D:\" /> my log folder does get created on the D drive, hence I would exclude permissions. Still looking for solution.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a C# custom action. You should never use vbscripts for your installer, as even Rob Mensching has a post on why this should never be the case, but even I have seen problems in production releases that use vbscripts, and trust me, it wasn't pretty (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx). Barring that, you should run your MSI with logging and see what's happening to that TARGETDIR property, by literally searching the log for TARGETDIR.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for that. In the meantime, I have found other ways to achieve this without including scripting.The most suitable solution for me will be to set the property values in my Bundle. Something like this:       <MsiPackage Id="AnyId" SourceFile="AnyMsi">
        <MsiProperty Name="TARGETDIR" Value="AnyPath"/>
 </MsiPackage>